# Why is my pygame display not responding while waiting for input?

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to use python to display image:

```py
import pygame
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
DisplayImage("Prologue.jpg", win)
```

And when it runs, nothing happened. It also happened for

```py
DisplayImage("Streets.jpg", win)
```

However, when I tried the exact same thing later on in the code, it ran perfectly.

I checked, the picture was in the same folder as the .py file, and I didn't type the name wrong.

The function is:

```py
def DisplayImage(imageName, screen):
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    Image = pygame.image.load(imageName).convert()
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    Image_rect = Image.get_rect().fit(screen_rect)
    Image = pygame.transform.scale(Image, Image_rect.size)
    screen.blit(Image, [0, 0])
    pygame.display.update()
```

Update:
I commented out all of the lines and copy and pasted that line out so it's the only line that runs. It runs perfectly.

Update 2:
Found the issue. The reason it doesn't work was that the pygame window was "not responding". I don't know what caused it to not respond, but in one of the test runs I didn't make it show "not responding", and the images were loaded fine. The "not responding" always shows up when I type in my player name, and the function looks like this:

```py
def createName():
    playerName = input("Enter the player name\n")
    desiredName = input("Is "+playerName+" the desired name?[1]Yes/[2]No\n")
    if desiredName == "1":
        return playerName
    elif desiredName == "2":
        playerName = createName()
```

Sometimes when I type the player name nothing happens, and the letters only show up after a while. If this happens, the pygame window is bound to not respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `input` in the application loop. `input` waits for an input. While the system is waiting for input, the application loop will halt and the game will not respond.

Use the `KEYDOWN` event instead of `input`:

```py
run = True
while run:
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key == pygame.K_1:
                # [...]
            if pygame.key == pygame.K_2:
                # [...]
```

---

Another option is to get the input in a separate thread.

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame
import threading

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

color = "red"
def get_input():
    global color
    color = input('enter color (e.g. blue): ')

input_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_input)
input_thread.start()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    window_center = window.get_rect().center
    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, color, window_center, 100)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: I didn't do this in an application loop. Also, I've tried to use keydown, which failed because it simply skipped over the options.

Comment: Is there any other way to go around this?

Comment: @RichardSu You can call input in a separat thread. I've extended the answer.

Comment: I tried another method, getting 2nd window for displaying which only declares itself when stuff needs to be displayed, which worked as well. Thank you!