# Why does my pygame screen go non responsive while waiting for user input?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to python programming and am trying to create a game for class.  Every time I run the program, before the user gets to put input in the surface screen goes non responsive.  What am I doing wrong?

#import modules needed
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

def main():

```
#Assigns Colors
ORANGE = (255, 127, 80)         #Background
BLACK = (0, 0, 0 )                      #Mountains
WHITE = (255,255,255)             #Snow  & Trees
BROWN = (61, 16, 16)               #moose & Mountains
GREEN = (0, 153, 0)                  #Trees
L_BROWN=(181, 101, 29)         #Tree Trunks
YELLOW =(255, 255, 204)         #Sky
BLUE = (67, 111, 181)               #Lake
LIME = (57, 255, 20)


#initiate modules
pygame.init()
done=False
#assign screen values and display captions
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Welcome To Michelle Era's Final Project - Moose Scene")

#start clock
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
fps = (60)

#Assign Variables
drink = " "
name = " "
welcome = " "
water= " "
quit = " "
i = 0
Moose_img = pygame.image.load('moose.png')
Beer_img = pygame.image.load('beer.png')
mikey_img=pygame.image.load('Mikey.jpg')
Water_img = pygame.image.load('water.png')
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri',25,False,False)
text=font.render("My text", True, YELLOW)
player_num = 0
moose_num = random.randrange(1,26)

while not done:
    pygame.event.pump()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
               
    screen.fill(ORANGE) #fills background orange

     #Draw Scene       
    def draw_mountains(screen, x,y):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK,(1,200,1000,100)) # Base of mountain
        x_offset=0
        while x_offset<1000:
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, WHITE, [[100+x_offset,100], [0+x_offset ,225], [200+x_offset, 225]], 0) # snow caps on mountain
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, BROWN, [[100+x_offset,120], [0+x_offset ,225], [200+x_offset, 230]], 0) 
            x_offset=x_offset+120#tells how many pixels to move over until you reached 1000
        
    def draw_trees(screen, x,y):
        x_offset=0
        while x_offset<1000:
            pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, GREEN, [27+x_offset,158,40,50], 0) #draws leaves starting at x27 to x 1000 every 50 pixels
            x_offset=x_offset +50 #tells how many pixels to move over until you reached 1000
            pygame.draw.line(screen,L_BROWN,[x_offset,200],[x_offset +10,250],8) #draws trunk starting at x0 to x 1000 every 50 pixels
            pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,[x_offset,207],[x_offset +10,250],1) #draws snow starting at x0 to x 1000 every 50 pixels
            x_offset=x_offset +50

    def draw_lake(screen, x,y):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE, [0,300,1000,200],0)# draws the lake
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,L_BROWN,[0,500,1000,100],0) #draws grass

    def gameover():
        screen.fill(BLACK) #fills play surface
        pygame.display.flip() #updates the display
        gameOverFont=pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',17)
        gameOversurf = gameOverFont.render("A Big thank you to my brother Michael Era who originally painted the mural that was the  inspiration for this project",True, YELLOW)
        gameOverRect = gameOversurf.get_rect()
        gameOverRect.midtop = (500,40)
        screen.blit(gameOversurf, gameOverRect)
        screen.blit(mikey_img, (200,100))
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(30)


             
    draw_mountains(screen, 0,0)
    draw_trees(screen,0,0)
    draw_lake(screen,300,400)
    screen.blit(Moose_img, (600,400))      
    welcome = font.render("WELCOME TO MOOSEVILLE", True, YELLOW)
    screen.blit(welcome, [300,50])
    pygame.display.update()

#
    
#GET user input        
        
    name=(input('What is your Moose named ? '))
    name=font.render("I like The Name " + str(name), True, YELLOW)

    draw_mountains(screen, 0,0)
    draw_trees(screen,0,0)
    draw_lake(screen,300,400)
    screen.blit(Moose_img, (600,400))
    screen.blit(name, (550, 355))
    pygame.display.update()


    num_game=font.render("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 25, can you guess it? ", True, LIME)
    screen.blit(num_game,(25,325))


    player_num=(input(" What is your guess 1 to 10: "))
    player_num = font.render('You Choose The Number: ' +str(player_num), True, LIME)
    screen.blit(player_num,(25,350))
    pygame.display.update()

    moose_num = random.randrange(1,11)
    moose_num=font.render('My number choice was : ' + str(moose_num), True, LIME)
    screen.blit(moose_num,(25,376))
    pygame.display.update()
       
    if player_num == moose_num:
        won=font.render('You Won!!!', True, YELLOW)
        screen.blit(won,(25,400))
        pygame.display.update()
    else:
        lose=font.render('You Lose!' , True, YELLOW)
        screen.blit(lose,(25,400))
        pygame.display.update()

    quit = input('Do you want to try again? y or n ')
    if quit == "n":
        gameover()
    else:
        done=False
                     
               

    pygame.quit()
```

main()

Comment: Your screen will not update until it gets to the end of the loop, but `input` is preventing the code from proceeding. You will have to display everything and ask for the user input in two separate steps. It is also a little unconventional to define a function inside a while loop. You should move that outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need both `event.pump()` and `event.get()`, just use event.get in the loop as now. Also, you don't usually define functions inside a while loop.  They would be outside the loop and called from inside it. You are also calling both `event.pump` and `event.get` and getting input via "input."

You also call `pygame.quit()` inside the while loop.  Break this up into a bunch of functions.

```
main() - this calls all the others
get_input()
draw_screen()
etc
```

Also the numbers game says:

`num_game=font.render("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 25, can you guess it? "`

and then asks for:

`player_num=(input(" What is your guess 1 to 10: "))`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in the application loop. `input` waits for an input. While the system is waiting for input, the application loop will halt and the game will not respond. Use the `KEYDOWN` event instead of `input`:

```py
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # [...]
```

Either implement a textbox (see [How to create a text input box with pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390231/how-to-create-a-text-input-box-with-pygame/64613666#64613666))
or get the input in a separate thread (see [Why is my display not responding while waiting for input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111782/why-is-my-display-not-responding-while-waiting-for-input/67113040#67113040)).